# is there a betterway to merge json arrays into one

Tags: javascript, json

```
//working with vmware software
//so I can't use any JS library or python(i can but the method is harder there)
var env1ParsedScriptOutput='[{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput1"},{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput1"}]';
var env2ParsedScriptOutput='[{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput2"},{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput2"}]';
var env3ParsedScriptOutput='[{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput3"},{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput3"}]';

function rmvBrackets (){
  var newJson = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    var txt = arguments[i].replace(/(\[|\])/g,'');
    newJson.push(txt);
  }
  return newJson;
};
var allResults = rmvBrackets(env1ScriptOutput,env2ParsedScriptOutput,env3ParsedScriptOutput).toString();
var allScriptExecParsedOutput = '['+allResults+']'; //final return, this will be processed on another object
```

can anyone help me and enlightme. this is my code I've crafted with try and fail method.
I know there is must be a better way to do thisbut I just started to code with JS

Comment: Look at `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`

Comment: `const result = JSON.stringify([env1ParsedScriptOutput, env2ParsedScriptOutput, env3ParsedScriptOutput].flatMap(JSON.parse))` should work for example.

Comment: Why are you not just parsing them and treating them like arrays?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would concat it and apply Json.parse to turn it to an array.

Then use flat() to flatten it.

```js
var env1ParsedScriptOutput =
    '[{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput1"},{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput1"}]';
var env2ParsedScriptOutput =
    '[{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput2"},{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput2"}]';
var env3ParsedScriptOutput =
    '[{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput3"},{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput3"}]';

const concat = `[${env1ParsedScriptOutput},${env2ParsedScriptOutput},${env3ParsedScriptOutput}]`;
const output = JSON.parse(concat).flat();

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks man this did the work

Answer (score 1):

You `JSON.parse` which return array and Spread operator like this

```js
var env1ParsedScriptOutput='[{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput1"},{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput1"}]';
var env2ParsedScriptOutput='[{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput2"},{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput2"}]';
var env3ParsedScriptOutput='[{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput3"},{"somevalue":"stringified_jsonOuput3"}]';

let results = [
  ...JSON.parse(env1ParsedScriptOutput),
  ...JSON.parse(env2ParsedScriptOutput),
  ...JSON.parse(env3ParsedScriptOutput)
];

console.log(results);
```